# Can I change the order of a functional dervative and a partial derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

For variables $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and functions $F,G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, can I assume that this equation holds?

$$
\frac{\delta\left(\displaystyle \frac{\partial (G(F))(y)}{\partial y}\right)}{\delta F(x)}
=
\frac{\partial\left(\displaystyle \frac{\delta (G(F))(y)}{\delta F(x)}\right)}{\partial y}
$$

In other words, do the two derivative operators commute, i.e.

$$
\left[\frac{\delta}{\delta F(x)},\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right] = 0\,?
$$

Can this be proven somehow, or is there some well-known theorem that states this?

If this doesn't hold in the general case, does it change he matter if $F$ and $G$ are the same function? I.e, does

$$
\frac{\delta\left(\displaystyle \frac{\partial F(y)}{\partial y}\right)}{\delta F(x)}
=
\frac{\partial\left(\displaystyle \frac{\delta F(y)}{\delta F(x)}\right)}{\partial y}
=
\frac{\partial\,\delta(y-x)}{\partial y}
$$

hold?

**Edit:** I got the question "Which kind of definitions are you using"? This is for a string theory course, and we are using a functional derivative $\frac{\delta}{\delta f(\tau')}$ subject to

$$
\frac{\delta f(\tau)}{\delta f(\tau')} = \delta(\tau-\tau')
$$

and

$$
\int_a^b d\tau g(\tau)\delta(\tau-\tau') = g(\tau'),
$$

provided that $\tau'\in (a,b)$.

Comment: What is that $Y(r)$? In particular, how is $F$ related to $Y(r)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar In my case $F$ and $Y$ are actually the same function, but I thought I would make the question more general so that $F$ can be dependent on $Y$ in any way. Does it makes a big difference?

Comment: This is way too vague to give an answer. Which kind of definitions are you using?

Comment: @daw Which kind of definitions are there? I have updated the questions with the details we have got about the functional derivative.

Comment: @daw Does it matter which definition we are using? If it matters, is what I've written that I know about the version we are using enough?

Comment: Yes, the definitions matter, always.  A "derivative" in Banach space, for example, needs to be qualified as either Frechet or Gateaux as the two definitions are different and only coincide under certain circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the order of the functional derivative and the partial derivative can be changed. Since a functional derivative can be defined as

$$\frac{\delta (G(F))(y)}{\delta F(x)} = \frac{\operatorname{d}(G(F+h\delta_x))(y)}{\operatorname{d}h},$$

where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac delta function $\delta_x(y) = \delta(y-x)$, we get

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle \frac{\delta\left(\displaystyle \frac{\partial (G(F))(y)}{\partial y}\right)}{\delta F(x)}
= & \displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{d}\left(\displaystyle \frac{\partial (G(F+h\delta_x))(y)}{\partial y}\right)}{\operatorname{d}h} \\
= & \displaystyle \frac{\partial\left(\displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{d} (G(F+h\delta_x))(y)}{\operatorname{d}h}\right)}{\partial y} \\
= & \displaystyle \frac{\partial\left(\displaystyle \frac{\delta (G(F))(y)}{\delta F(x)}\right)}{\partial y}. \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: You are aware of the standard examples of functions where taking partial derivatives does not commute?

Comment: @daw No, I'm not; can you give such an example?

Comment: One example is $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$$ which yields $\partial_x \partial_y f(0,0) = 1, \partial_y \partial_x f(0,0) = -1$. The theorem which allows you to interchange the orders of differentiation is called (among other things) Schwarz's theorem.

Comment: @SV-97 Can $f$ be continuously extended to the entire plane?

Comment: @SV-97 Ah, thanks. So if the function is not twice differentiable in some points, you cannot interchange the order of differentiation in those points, but everywhere else it should be fine according to Schwarz's theorem?

Comment: @Filippo I think so, if you choose $f(0,0) = 0$. See the plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E3*y+-+x*y%5E3%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29) (keep in mind that for $x=y\neq 0$, $f(x,y)=0$).

Comment: @HelloGoodbye If it's not twice differentiable in some point then you can't even differentiate it twice ;) It's about being continuously differentiable: if your function is twice differentiable such that the second order derivatives are continuous then you may interchange the order (it actually states a bit more but this is the relevant bit). Note that this is an implication rather than an equivalence, so you may also find functions with non-continuous second derivatives that still statisfy $\partial_1 \partial_2 f = \partial_2 \partial_1 f$.

Comment: @Filippo which $f$ do you mean? The one I've given as an example?

Comment: @SV-97 Yes, thank you for asking. But the comment of HelloGoodbye already solved the problem :) (To the OP: I already thanked you in another comment, but it seems like the comment got deleted)